# Use array mapping to create react elements in another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently I am getting data from an API and storing those results into an array. The problem, when I do the array mapping to the child component, it never executes because the array is empty to begin with. How can I execute the array mapping when the array has data in it. I tried inline conditional such as doing {array.length > 0 ? //do array mapping}. I also tried making the array both global and an array that is a state of the parent component.

//React Router

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

import Main from '../components/Main';

export default () => {
  return <Route path="/" component={Main}/>
};
```

//Main component

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
// import bgImage from './ignasi_pattern_s.png';
import Child1 from './Children/Child1';
import axios from 'axios';

const QUERY_URL = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?api-key=";

//****Tried global array declaration and as a state property but both do not work.
// var articles = [];


class Main extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            search: "",
            articles: []
        }

        this.getTopic = this.getTopic.bind(this);
        this.executeSearch = this.executeSearch.bind(this);
    }

    getTopic(event) {

        this.setState({
            search: event.target.value
        });
    }

    executeSearch(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        axios.get(QUERY_URL + "&q=" + this.state.search).then((response) => {

            for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){

                this.state.articles.push({
                    headline: response.data.response.docs[i].lead_paragraph
                })
            }
        }); 
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Main" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${"http://aiburn.com/files/articles/creating_professional_business_backgrounds/06.gif"})`}}>

                <div className="page-header">

                    <h1>{getNiceName(this.props.routes)}{' '}
                        <small>page</small>
                    </h1>

                    <h1>Search For Something</h1>

                    <form onSubmit={this.executeSearch}>
                        <input type="text" value={this.state.search} onChange={this.getTopic}/>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">Search</button>
                    </form>

                </div>

                <div className="container Main-content">

                    //Trouble here mapping the array to the child component.
                    //This never executes because the array is empty to begin with. 
                    {this.state.articles.length > 0 ?

                        {this.state.articles.map((item, index) => {


                            return <Child1 
                                key={index}
                                headline={item.headline}
                            />;

                        })}
                    }

                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

Main.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node,
    routes: PropTypes.array
};

export default Main;
```

//Child Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Child1 extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            <div className="container">
                <h1>{this.props.headline}<span><button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">Save</button></span></h1>
            </div>

        </div>;
    }
}

export default Child1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to check if `this.state.articles.length > 0`. You can just proceed to call `this.state.articles.map` immediately. `map`, when given an empty array, just returns the empty array - it does nothing with it.

That is, `[].map(x => whatever(x)) === []`.

Therefore, even if `this.state.articles.length <= 0`, you will just end up rendering the empty collection (that is, nothing at all).

Comment: well, even when the array has data in it, it will show nothing. Meaning that the Child component never got the index of the array

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this might be an issue or not, but seems like there is syntax error with inline conditional. The code should be like this.

```
<div className="container Main-content">
    {this.state.articles.length > 0 ?
        this.state.articles.map((item, index) => {
           return <Child1 
             key={index}
             headline={item.headline}
           />;
         }) : null
    }
</div>
```

Also, as @evocatus mentioned there is no need to put check on length as map already handles this.

If you want to render a different component when the array is empty, you can put that element instead of null.

Comment: Thanks for the input, The problem was I was not doing a setState after pushing into the array